# Validates_length_of using within, but the field shouldn't be mandatory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing this:

```
validates_length_of  :some_field, :within => 0..10
```

And a empty field returns an error, why is that?

How can I check to make sure it is between 0..10, but the field in the form isn't mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close:

```
validates_length_of  :some_field, :within => 0..10, :allow_blank => true
```

You can change the zero minimum size, since it will only be triggered when there is some input.

See also the validation [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_length_of).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `:allow_blank` as an option to allow this:

```
validates_length_of :some_field, :within => 0..10, :allow_blank => true
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

validates_length_of :some_field, :within => [0..10], :if => :some_field?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's a nil value instead of an empty string  that it gets validated against ?

```
irb(main):006:0> ''.length
=> 0
irb(main):007:0> nil.length
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.length
    from (irb):7
```